# Python: Insert nested value IF doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
'python_task': {'python_file': '/test_script.py', 'parameters': ['--first_param', 'One', '--second_param', 2,]}
```

I would like to check the dictionary to see if `--year` and `--month` exists. If not, then add the current year and month so the final dict looks like this:

```
'python_task': {'python_file': '/test_script.py', 'parameters': ['--first_param', 'One', '--second_param', 2, '--year', 2023, '--month', 08]}
```

I have a function to check the dict:

```
def check_dict_key(item_dict: Dict[str, Any], key: str) -> bool:
    """
    Check if the key is included in given dictionary, and has a valid value.
    :param item_dict: a dictionary to test
    :type item_dict: Dict[str, Any]
    :param key: a key to test
    :type key: str
    :return: result to check
    :type: bool
    """
    return bool(key in item_dict and item_dict[key] is not None)
```

but I am not sure how to the insert the values in order as shown.
Using datetime to get year and month should be used but just not sure how.

This was my starting IF statement:

```
if not utils.check_dict_key(task_params, "--year"):
            task_params["parameters"]['--year']
            task_params["parameters"]['']: date=datetime(
                year=task_params[parameters]['']   
            )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may have jumped the gun a little bit but wanted to post my answer in case anyone else finds this question.

This code worked:

```
if not utils.check_dict_key(task_params, "--year"):
            current_year = datetime.now().year
            parameters = task_params['python_task']['parameters']
            parameters.extend(['--year', str(current_year)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your sample code and code template.

First, let's look at your check_dict_key function.
The function as written will return True if the key 'parameters exists and and the `item_dict['parameters']` is not None. This is a redundant check, since I assume if the key 'parameters' exists, `item_dict['parameters']` will also exist.

Second, in your if statement you seem to think the contents of python_tasks `task_parms[parameters]` yields a dictionary having different keys, given your existing input sample this is not the case, `task_parms['paraneters']` yields a list, which can't process the code as written.

One way to fix your issue is to reformat your input data as illustrated below:

```
indict = {'python_task': {'python_file': '/test_script.py', 'parameters': {'--first_param': 'One', '--second_param': 2}}}
```

now calling `check_dict_key(indict['python_task']['parameters'], '--first_param')` yields `True`, and
calling `check_dict_key(indict['python_task']['parameters'], '--year')` yields `False`.

To complete what you are trying to do, given the new data structure, you will need to do something along the lines of the following:

```
from typing import Any
from datetime import date, datetime

indict = {'python_task': {'python_file': '/test_script.py', 'parameters': {'--first_param': 'One', '--second_param': 2}}}
for outer_key in indict:
    if not check_dict_key(indict[outer_key]['parameters'], "--year"):
        indict[outer_key]['parameters']['--year'] = datetime.now().year
    if not check_dict_key(indict[outer_key]['parameters'], "--month"):
        indict[outer_key]['parameters']['--month'] = datetime.now().month
```

Running the above code will yield the following output for indict:

```
{'python_task': {'python_file': '/test_script.py',
  'parameters': {'--first_param': 'One',
   '--second_param': 2,
   '--year': 2023,
   '--month': 8}}}
```